# Use JS file for a Prestashop's module

Tags: javascript, module, prestashop, admin, call

I can't use a JS file for my module's admin configuration in Prestashop. I tried every docs and advises I read here and there but can't do anything with them.

I used the displayBackOfficeHeader hook as you can see here :

```php
public function install()
    {
        if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
        }
        
        if (!parent::install() ||
        !$this->registerHook('leftColumn') ||
        !$this->registerHook('header') ||
        !$this->registerHook('displayBackOfficeHeader') ||
        !Configuration::updateValue('MM_CUSTOM_PAGENAME', 'Test') ||
        // CREATE MM_CUSTOM_TEMPLATE FOR EVERY CATEGORIES ADDED
        $this->defineCategorieTableName() ||
        !Configuration::updateValue('MM_CUSTOM_FONT', 'Test') ||
        !Configuration::updateValue('MM_CUSTOM_CATEGORIE', 'Test')
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

And created a simple function :

```php
 public function hookDisplayBackOfficeHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/configure.js');
    }
```

The `<script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/mm_custom/views/js/configure.js"></script>` is well added in the  tag up there.

But if I type this in the configure.js file :

```js
console.log('hello');
const categories = document.querySelectorAll('.cat')
console.log(categories);
```

I get this in the console :

[image: console screenshot]

As if it has no access to the html down there we can see in the dev tool.
I'm not getting out of this trouble for 2 days...

Thanks to help guys ;)

EDIT: If I put the <script src: ....> in the .tpl itself, it works fine. But I won't have access to elements in an automatically generated form on the same front page (but not in the .tpl I created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // code...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, it works perfectly !
I suspected a lot the fact that, in the <head>, it was just read before the content..
Prestashop is so badly done omg, and the doc is almost useless. Terrible.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's PrestaShop's fault that you forgot about it :-) These are basics of JS but I might improve the documentation a bit to remind people of using event listener ;-)

Comment: Oh you are in Prestashop development sorry aha. The thing I don't understand is why there is no way to import a js file in the bottom of the <body> tag ? It looks weird to have it in the <head> isn't it ?
And yes, the doc has a lot of things not mentionned at all.
But yeah, i'm using your services and the website is working well of course so I won't complain that much. Thanks again ;)

Comment: No worries! You're right: it should be mentioned. Ideally, there should be a way to add JS easily at the bottom of the page :)